# Create own widget in C# and add to Table

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I learning to create android app in C# (VisualStudio) and I need create table with my own widget.
I upload data for my server SQL. Any idea how can I do this?

[Presentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3290t.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Searched for examples? Please try and ask more specific.

Comment: Can you please be more clear? Do you require these details in cross-platform or in Android alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement is for cross-platform, then you are probably looking for a ListView or CollectionView. Please refer to the below links.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance#custom-cells
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-list

In case, if you are looking it only for Android, please refer to the below link to customize the appearance of the ListView as you desire.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/list-view/customizing-appearance

Comment: @Andrzej Paw, If my reply helps you, please remember to mark my reply as an answer. Thanks...